# Firebase Authentication is failing with "Developer Error" after uploading apk to google play store

Tags: android, apk, release

I am using Firebase Authentication for authenticating user in my application.

Everything was working fine till I was working on debug build of my application. But the moment I have uploaded the signed apk in playstore, my user authentication service always fails with "Developer Error" message.

On some web research, I find out that I need to generate SHA certificate for my signed apk also. I have generated SHA with locally created ".jks" file, which I have used to sign my application locally before uploading. I have added the generated SHA keys to firebase project console and generated new google-services.json file. Even this approach has not helped me.

I am suspecting that this is happening because I am using "Google Play App Signing (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)" which is again changing the certificate. Can anyone please help me and let me know what is the right process for updating SHA keys for release apk.

If play store is doing the app-signing, then how can it be the part of "google-services.json" where SHA keys must be mentioned beforehand?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open App signing section in **Google Play Console**, and get **SHA1** of **app signing certificate**

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: I have enabled google app signing as well as has pasted app signing certificate and upload certificate too, still I am getting Firebase authentication error with my published app. Please suggest if something I am missing

Answer (score 0):

if you are using local .jks file for signing, you dont need to google play app signing. after adding your .jsk file's fingerprint into firebase console. just sync it in android studio or try to run the app on your phone first after that build a new signed apk. Then upload it on playstore.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I wanted Google to manage my keys, hence I have opted for this approach. Rafal's suggestion has worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042701/6943737