# Firebase OTP not working after uploading app to Playstore

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication, numbers

I have an app with firebase with OTP verification. Its OTP was working fine even after uploading to playstore. For last some days it stop working. I updated the app with new google services.json.It is working fine in debug mode and release apk. But after uploading to playstore phone does not recieve OTP message. I have added SHA - 1 and SHA - 256 key from play console to firebase project settings, still its not working. Can anybody tell me why its happening all of the sudden?

Comment: tried after sometime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324249/firebase-phone-auth-not-working-when-published-android

Comment: Did you changed your PC? Compare release SHA key of Firebase console with  release key from gradle task (generated from android studio).

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) might help.

Comment: Wow, It worked. I put  app signing certificate keys from playstore in firebase console. It starts working.

Are these keys keep changing when upload an apk to playstore?