# Flutter phone Authentication with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i want to ask if there is some permissions required for phone authentication in Firebase flutter to work on android real devices like after releasing the app ?
When i'm building the app on real device it work perfectly but when i release the app it doesn't work ,ths is the error i got *this app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase console*
ex: like we know for the internet permission we put inside the android_manifest for the app to work on internet

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042701/9316174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey all of you thnks for the answer you provide,the mistake was; i release the app and continue to use the same debug SHA-1 key while i was supposed to use the release SHA-1 key , so to anyone who will meet this kind of problem should first change the release key in the Firestore console before attempting to make any other changes

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to use firebase for database services only then there is no need to provide SHA 1 key and package name, But since you are using firebase authentication service you have to provide all these things so that firebase authentication works perfectly.

for Package name follow :-
ProjectRoot ->android ->src ->main -> Android manifest

[image]

And for Generating SHA1 key [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app)

After getting both these things Go to Project Setting in Firebase Console inside project scroll a bit you can see package name and sha1 key enter those and you are ready to go.

Comment: I did all of these things, I checked the package name and the SHA-1 key to see if they are the same, which I found the same so I don't know the problem

Comment: keep a look at this video you might get what you are doing wrong https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YH7lyyrCCM

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using firebase, add both SHA-1 and SHA-256 certificate in firebase console settings

[image: click here to open screenshot]