# Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication return success but don't send sms code verification

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication

I developed an android app with phone number authentication, when I published it on the play store it didn't work anymore.

In the debug version I received the code via SMS once and it didn't work anymore.

With this phone number it works, it just doesn't work with my real number as a test

1 - The access to phone is enable on dashboard
2 - SHA-1 is set in projet

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  //with support libraries
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



Future<void> verifyPhone() async {

    final PhoneCodeSent smsOTPSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      print("smsOTPSent");
      print(forceCodeResend);
      print(verId);
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsOTPDialog(context).then((value) {
        print('sign in');
      });
    };

    try {

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: "+55" + this.telController.text, // PHONE NUMBER TO SEND OTP
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verId) {
          //Starts the phone number verification process for the given phone number.
          //Either sends an SMS with a 6 digit code to the phone number specified, or sign's the user in and [verificationCompleted] is called.
          this.verificationId = verId;
          print("verId " + verId);
        },
        codeSent: smsOTPSent, // WHEN CODE SENT THEN WE OPEN DIALOG TO ENTER OTP.
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 20),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
          print("verificationCompleted " + this.telController.text);
          print(phoneAuthCredential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException exceptio) {
          print("fail");
          print('${exceptio.message}');
        }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
    print(e.printStackTrace());
  }
}



verificaLogado(){
  print("chamou: verificaLogado()");
  print(_auth.currentUser());
  _auth.currentUser().then((user) {
    if (user != null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }else{
      print("não logado");
    }
  });
}


signIn() async {
  try {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsOTP,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    _showDialog('Sucesso', 'Autenticado com o número de telefone ' + user.phoneNumber);
    _setPhoneFCM(currentUser.uid, currentUser.phoneNumber);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
    print(e.printStackTrace());
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I discovered the problem, even following all the guidelines and registering test phone numbers, for some reason my network's IP was blocked on the firebase server.

When I tried using the cell phone's 4G network it worked

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution; its is on the SHA-1 key; in firebase I configureted the SHA-1 that I get on Android Studio keystool; but when I publish a app on Google Play Store; He replaces the SHA-1 for another key to delivery the app on Play Store; You can find the new in Google Play Console>Release Management>App siging; in App siging certificate.
config this in firebase projet and wow; its working.

1 - You digitally sign each version with your upload key before publishing it to a track on the Play Console.
2 - Google Play uses the upload certificate to verify your identity and re-signs your version with the app's subscription key for distribution.
3 - Each Android device verifies that the version's app signature certificate matches that of the installed app before updating it.

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042343/firebase-authentication-is-failing-with-developer-error-after-uploading-apk-to)